# Use of undeclared type 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am using segue to transfer a file to next UIViewController.
The name of the first View is RecordSoundsViewController and the name of the second view is PlaySoundsViewController.
When I use segue.destinationViewController as! PlaySoundsViewController it shows an error " use of undeclared type 'PlaySoundsViewController ".
I don't know how to declare the type of UIViewController. 
Please Help

[image]

Comment: use import PlaySoundsViewController

Answer (score 1):

Are you using multiple targets? If so select the applicable targets for your class in Target-membership from identity inspector.

Or else check the access level for the class public, private.

Answer (score 0):

Please try follows.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayVC") as! PlaySoundsViewController

vc."id to receive" = "the value to send"

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.